# I have an array I am having trouble displaying it in these tables format

Tags: php, arrays

This is Array. Below this I have also uploaded the image which is the output i want. It has 6 different values in a portfolio A, B,C,E,IE,IB it's a shot name of category name. If you see the upload image, you will understand.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0047
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 50488
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0217
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 44256
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *1278
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 9213
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *2371
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 128563
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *2801
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 4766
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 30061
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *6400
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 7972
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => A
            [value] => 37255
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0217
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 52213
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *1278
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 7349
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 133558
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5656
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 32665
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *6400
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 42907
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => B
            [value] => 114178
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0217
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 75530
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *1051
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 9453
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *1278
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 9833
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *2801
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 1522
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 164912
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5656
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 12500
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *6400
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 117378
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => C
            [value] => 86890
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0217
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 76279
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *1278
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 5415
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *2801
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 7660
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 235189
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5656
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 43237
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *6400
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 85458
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => E
            [value] => 239417
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => IB
            [value] => 49248
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => IB
            [value] => 23670
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *0217
            [s_c] => IE
            [value] => 38588
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5470
            [s_c] => IE
            [value] => 20989
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *5656
            [s_c] => IE
            [value] => 22768
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *6400
            [s_c] => IE
            [value] => 23339
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [portfolio] => *9749
            [s_c] => IE
            [value] => 11430
        )

)
```

[image]

May I am trying in this way but I am doing something wrong. Means what I am doing is making the table wrong.

```
<?php
    foreach ($chart1 as $da) {
?>
    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $da['portfolio'];
            
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "C" && $da['s_c'] == "C"){
            echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']);
            $cash_totle += $da['value'];
        }
        
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "E" && $da['s_c'] == "e"){
           echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']); 
                 $us_enquity_totle += $da['value']; 
        }
        
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "IE" && $da['s_c'] == "ie"){
            echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']);
            $int_eq_total += $da['value'];
        }
        
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "IE" && $da['s_c'] == "ie"){
            echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']);
                $int_bnd_totle += $da['value'];
        }
        
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "B" && $da['s_c'] == "b"){
            echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']); 
                $us_bad_total += $da['value'];
        }
        
        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($da['s_c'] == "A" && $da['s_c'] == "a"){
            echo ($da['value'] == 0)? "-":number_format($da['value']);
                $alts_total += $da['value'];
        }
        
        ?></td>
                  

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to figure stuff out while there is drawing going on, it's often easier to focus strictly on setting up the data so that drawing the table is just a simple loop.

In this case, each time you encounter a new portfolio, you can create a new, empty 'row' in your data structure, and as you encounter data you can fill it in.

Let's say that the big array above is in a variable named $rawData. Each element in the array fills in one value in your table.

```
$formattedData = [];

foreach($rawData as $datum) {
    $portfolio = $datum['portfolio'];

    if (!isset($formattedData[$portfolio])) {
        // this is the first time we have learned about this portfolio
        // Create an empty row in the formatted data
        $formattedData[$portfolio] = ['C' => 0, 'E' => 0, 'IE' => 0, 'IB' => 0, 'B' => 0, 'A' => 0];
    }

    // now you can find the column that this particular datum
    // belongs to and set its value.
    $formattedData[$portfolio][$datum['s_c']] = $datum['value'];
}

print_r($formattedData);
```

Now you have an array of arrays, but each of the inner arrays matches a row in your table:

```
Array
(
    [*0047] => Array
        (
            [C] => 0
            [E] => 0
            [IE] => 0
            [IB] => 0
            [B] => 0
            [A] => 50488
        )

    [*0217] => Array
        (
            [C] => 75530
            [E] => 76279
            [IE] => 38588
            [IB] => 0
            [B] => 52213
            [A] => 44256
        )

    ... etc
```

You could choose at this point to sort your array if you wanted to.

Note: I'm not sure what your `*_total` is supposed to be, but you can track totals in the loop above as well if you want to. You would probably keep the totals in a separate array.

Now writing the html is a piece of cake:

```
print '<table>';
   // ... add your header stuff, then

foreach($formattedData as $portfolio => $row) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>' . $portfolio . '</td>';
    foreach($row as $columnValue) {
        print '<td>' . $columnValue . '</td>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
}

print '</table>';
```

(Note that I use `print` for even the regular html markup, rather than embedding a bunch of `<?php` tags in the middle of my html. It's a style thing, but it makes things like loops a lot easier to read.)

The result is, instead of one confusing loop where you might have to go back and figure out how to fill in values for a previous row, you have two loops, each with only one job, each easy to debug. In between you have a moment you can inspect the data to make sure the first loop got it right, so you can isolate bugs easily.